# Apply function to current click and remove function for other click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to apply function `addDiv()` to the current clicked an element and it's working fine, but it's not removing the function `addDiv()` on another click. When click on the text, the addDiv() function is applied to a div tag and added a sample text, but need to apply this addDiv() function only on the current clicked the tag. can someone help me?

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/a0L2jj1y/1/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Tesing 1
</div>
<div>
    Tesing 2
</div>
<div>
    Tesing 3
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){

    function addDiv(){

    $('<div class="txt"/>').text('sample text added').appendTo('.clicked');

    }

    $(document).on('click', function(event){
        var clickedTag = event.target
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');

        if($(clickedTag).text().length >= 1){
            $(clickedTag).addClass('clicked');
            addDiv();
        } else {
            // I need to remove addDiv();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it's no clear, you want to delete the added text or delete the addDiv() function?

Comment: `toggleClass()`

Comment: @N.Malloul, trying to delete the addDiv() function

Comment: @Issac What do you mean be "delete the addDiv() function"? Remove sideeffects it did? Unbind click handler for already clicked elements?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko When i click on text, the `addDiv()` function is applied on div tag and added a sample text, but i need to apply this  `addDiv()` function only on the current clicked tag

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(function(){

  function addDiv(){

  $('<div class="txt"/>').text('sample text added').appendTo('.clicked');

  }
  $(document).on('click', function(event){
  var clickedTag = event.target
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');

  if($(clickedTag).text().length >= 1){
  $(clickedTag).addClass('clicked');
  addDiv();

  } else {
  $(clickedTag).unbind();
  }

  });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

> i need to apply this addDiv() function only on the current clicked tag

To accomplish this you could simply pass current event target to `addDiv` function. So it would append text only to the div being clicked.

```js
$(function(){

    function addDiv(to){
      $('<div class="txt"/>').text('sample text added').appendTo(to);
    }

    $(document).on('click', 'div', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation()
        addDiv(event.target)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Tesing 1
</div>
<div>
    Tesing 2
</div>
<div>
    Tesing 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i've tried to simplify your approach. try this

[here is jsfiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/kfxp29tm/)

```
<style>
div{color:gray;}
div.clicked{color:red;}
</style>

<div id="one">Testing 1</div>
<div id="two">Testing 2</div>
<div id="three">Testing 3</div>

<script>
$('div').on('click', function(event){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).append('sample text added');
    $('div:not(#'+id+')').removeClass('clicked');
});
</script>
```